# ssh to server exits w/225 after reboot of Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ssh

I rebooted Ubuntu 20.04 via an ssh session using init 6. Once it came back up, I can connect, but it fails with an exit code of 255. I've tried public key and password auth. Here is the tail end of ssh -vv 10.0.2.184 - and it shows that the authentication worked! But I can't figure out why it dies with 255...

```
debug1: Server accepts key: /opt/openssh-8.9p1/etc/ssh_host_rsa_key RSA SHA256:1Dt6UXfkDXMyVKjPZ56Sj3lCoyefwgP2ZG7BNJLE9uE
Authenticated to 10.0.2.184 ([10.0.2.184]:22) using "publickey".
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /root/.ssh/known_hosts for 10.0.2.184 / (none)
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /root/.ssh/known_hosts2 for 10.0.2.184 / (none)
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: hostkeys file /root/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: host key found matching a different name/address, skipping UserKnownHostsFile update
debug1: Remote: /root/.ssh/authorized_keys:15: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: Remote: /root/.ssh/authorized_keys:15: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 4 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: channel 0: setting env LANG = "C"
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: chan_shutdown_read: channel 0: (i0 o0 sock -1 wfd 5 efd 7 [write])
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: chan_shutdown_write: channel 0: (i3 o1 sock -1 wfd 6 efd 7 [write])
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to 10.0.2.184 closed.
Transferred: sent 3140, received 3232 bytes, in 0.6 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 5192.6, received 5344.7
debug1: Exit status 255
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The error log is saying that `/root/.ssh/known_hosts` does not exist, which raises a couple of questions: (0) are you trying to SSH as root? (1) are you using a script or automated process to SSH into the machine? 

Comment: I've tried root - for which it was working before the reboot using an rsa public key auth and it worked. I've also tried a regular user, for which it allows me to use a password since it is in a private LAN network address - and it allows me to enter the password, but drops out with th 255 error code... It is really odd..

Comment: It should not be possible to SSH into an Ubuntu machine with `root` unless you've drastically modified many of the built-in permissions and security policies. The `255` error happens when the machine's signature  is not found in the `known_hosts` file. It should be possible to manually sign in with a non-`root` account and answer "Yes" to the prompt about adding the signature to `known_hosts`. After that, things should work as they did before 